# What is the maximum value of the MaxLocksPerFile JET4.0 registry value

Tags: c++, database, ms-access, odbc, registry

We have an MFC application that handles data with either MS-Access, Oracle or SQL-Server.
For a specific treatment, we have to use database transactions.

On Oracle or SQL-Server, everything is ok, but in MS-Access, we get the "File sharing lock count exceeded. Increase MaxLocksPerFile registry entry." message, as described here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815281

The question is what is the maximum coherent value that I can put there?
I was thinking about setting this value programatically at the appplication statup...

Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing entries as high as 50,000 through Google - but I suspect it's MaxInt. However, what is it that you are doing that's generating so many locks on the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I didn't see any article mentioning a maximum value.
Theoretically, the value being a DWORD, we could put up to FFFFFFFF (hex) or 4294967295 (decimal), but I'm not sure if it's a coherent value.